# Whitelist words in the spelling dictionary

Tags: dictionary, spellchecker

Is there a way to whitelist words in the spelling dictionary so that they will not be flagged as mispellings?

Can this be done for individual notebooks, all notebooks or both?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SpellCheckANotebook.html

Comment: @Alan I saw that. It does not appear to explain how to white list words.

Comment: @TylerDurden "If you use a word that is not part of the standard dictionary that the Wolfram System uses, you can click Add Word and that word will no longer be flagged as misspelled."  You can also do this as you type: misspelled words will be underlined in red, and you can right-click on them and add them.

Comment: Thanks. (for once my question actually IS a duplicate)

Answer (score 3):

You can monkey with the spelling correction settings in the Options Inspector. You can make changes that affect the either the current notebook (Selected Notebook) or for all notebooks (Global Preferences). Click on the toolbox icon (red arrow below). For global changes does to take effect, Mathematica must be restarted. For notebook changes to taken effect, the notebook must be reloaded.

[image: windows]

Answer (score 2):

The second part of the duplicate question describes the way to add custom words to the dictionary:

```
file = Import["words.txt","List"]
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, SpellingDictionaries -> {"CorrectWords" -> file}]
```

Replace \$FrontEndSession with \$FrontEnd for a permanent global setting.